# python inline append to list and create a variable

Tags: python

I have syntax error in this line:

```py
data = [{'name': project['name'], 'id': project['id']} for projects in api.all_projects() project = projects.to_dict() if project['name'].startswith('name')]
```

I'm not sure where's the problem.

Error message when I run the python cli:

```
>>> data = [{'name': project['name'], 'id': project['id']} for projects in api.all_projects() project = projects.to_dict() if project['name'].startswith('name')]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    data = [{'name': project['name'], 'id': project['id']} for projects in api.all_projects() project = projects.to_dict() if project['name'].startswith('name')]
                                                                                              ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: before going list comprension way , just create a normal loop 3-4 liner and then follow list comprehension

Comment: @Saeed It's not just about a missing `]`; that was your linter's inaccurate summary of the original problem. Now that you've closed what you *think* is a valid list comprehension, you're getting the expected syntax error.

Comment: Btw not only the code but also the error message would be easier to read if you had spread the comprehension over multiple physical lines like the answers did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform arbitrary assignment after the iteration statement; `project = projects.to_dict()` is not allowed where you put it.

You can use the walrus operator/assignment expression (`:=`) from 3.8+ as part of the `if` to achieve a similar effect though:

```
data = [{'name': project['name'], 'id': project['id']}
        for projects in api.all_projects()
        if (project := projects.to_dict())['name'].startswith('name')]
```

Other solutions, which avoid leaking the walrus-assigned variable, but are typically more verbose or ugly in one way or another, include:

1. Second loop over one-`tuple` or one-element `list`:

   ```
   data = [{'name': project['name'], 'id': project['id']}
           for projects in api.all_projects()
           for project in [projects.to_dict()]  # for project in (projects.to_dict(),) also works
           if (project['name'].startswith('name')]
   ```
2. `map`-ing with known class's method (if you actually know the class), or `operator.methodcaller`:

   ```
   data = [{'name': project['name'], 'id': project['id']}
           for project in map(Project.to_dict, api.all_projects())
           if (project['name'].startswith('name')]

   # Without knowing class
   from operator import methodcaller  # At top of file

   data = [{'name': project['name'], 'id': project['id']}
           for project in map(methodcaller('to_dict'), api.all_projects())
           if (project['name'].startswith('name')]
   ```
3. [chepner's inner generator expression solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78036945/364696) (a somewhat more verbose Python-level version of the `map`-based solutions)

Comment: I assume you know about CPython's optimization for alternative 1? I'd mention that, as it becomes exactly what they tried.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't know about the `walrus`. I'm reading about it.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Yeah, but it's a more recent optimization than the walrus (needs 3.9), and frankly I consider it uglier (it's such a hack to achieve such a minor benefit; I like the motivation, but the practical use is... meh). My usual choice is `map`+existing-function if possible, walrus if not, with `map`+`methodcaller` and the extra loop hack being reserved for rare cases where performance is more important than avoiding ugly hacks.

Answer (score 1):

Your linter's parser is guessing that `project = project.to_dict()` is the next statement, and is complaining that the list comprehension wasn't closed first.

You can't put arbitrary code in a list comprehension, which is the real problem.

You can write something like this, though.

```
data = [{'name': project['name'], 'id': project['id']}
          for project in (p.to_dict() for p in api.all_projects()) 
            if project['name'].startswith('name')]
```

A nested generator first decodes each project before your comprehension works with the resulting `dict` objects.

Answer (score -4):

I can't read your code.

To solve your title...

```
[data, variable, value].append(new_var := new_val)
```

Comment: I answered the question asked. The question asked did not have good guts and the code was a super complicated one liner. This *is* an answer directly to what was asked, and the gorilla operator is under used for this kind of thing. This *does* show succinctly something both useful and related. Why the bombing?